# Truncate the length of model serializer with many=True in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So in my project, I have a model Chat with many Messages. I want to have ChatSerializer with MessageSerializer inside and many=True.

However, I only want to include the last 50 Message models.

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'

class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    messages = MessageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = '__all__'
```

Is there anything I can add to the `messages = MessageSerializer(many=True)` to make it only return the latest 50 messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everybody was right about the `messages = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`. One thing that needs to be mentioned is ordering the list to be the last messages of the array.

For my implementation, I need the last 50 messages sorted in ascending timestamp (getting later) so this is what I did.

```
MESSAGE_COUNT = 50
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    messages = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_messages(self, chat):
        qs = Message.objects.filter(deal=deal).order_by('timestamp')
        if len(qs) > MESSAGE_COUNT:
            qs = qs[len(qs)-MESSAGE_COUNT:]
        return MessageSerializer(instance=qs, many=True).data
```

Comment: I included `order_by` in both variants of my answer (without knowing the exact field name and assuming you wanted the latest message first). You ordering puts the oldest of the 50 messages first. Good to know you solved it.

Comment: This is not a performant solution. You are loading all results from the database just to determine the length of existing records. What you have above is the same as simply: `return MessageSerializer(instance=Message.objects.filter(deal=deal).order_by("-timestamp)[:MESSAGE_COUNT], many=True).data`. The solution I just provided only loads the required data instead of potentially loading thousands (tens of thousands) of messages just to return the last 50.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `SerializerMethodField` within `ChatSerializer` as follows:

```
messages = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_messages(self, chat):
    qs = Message.objects.filter(chat=chat).order_by('-date')[:50]
    return MessageSerializer(instance=qs, many=True).data
```

This runs a separate query for every `Chat` instance, but it only fetches the required number of rows. You'd have to customize the field names (`chat`, `date`) as applicable.

---

The alternative syntax @spiritsree is aiming at results in the same SQL, using implicit rather than explicit filtering:

```
qs = chat.messages.order_by('-date')[:50]
```

One thing to avoid is using `prefetch_related('messages')` in the `queryset` of the `ViewSet` that returns the `Chat` list as that prefetch won't be used at all and would haul in all messages from the database only to be discarded unused.

---

The [subquery alternative](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26780#comment:9) dismissed in another answer as slow is in fact quite interesting. It saves you as many roundtrips to the database as there are Chats. In exchange however, the database has to execute twice as many queries internally.

The excess queries being quite lightweight (selecting a small number of messages by id and ordering them), the saved roundtrips may easily make up for them. In my quick tests this method was more than 10x as fast as using `SerializerMethodField`. It may depend to some extent on the data; test it for yourself:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.db.models import Prefetch, Subquery, OuterRef

class ChatViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    prefetch = Prefetch(
        'messages',
        queryset=Message.objects
            .filter(id__in=Subquery(Message.objects
                .filter(chat=OuterRef('chat_id'))
                .order_by('-date')
                .values_list('id', flat=True)[:4]))
            .order_by('-date')
    )

    queryset = Chat.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)** to do that.

```
MESSAGE_COUNT = 50
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    messages = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_messages(self, obj):
        return MessageSerializer(obj.messages[:MESSAGE_COUNT ], many=True).data
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. If you refer to the field `messages` in the method `get_messages` that is used to populate that very field, isn't this kind of a circular reference?

Comment: @EndreBoth sorry. That was a mistake.

Comment: Use `obj.messages.all()` or `obj.messages.order_by('-date')` to get a queryset; just `obj.messages` gives you the `RelatedManager` of the `Chat` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Tobey is unrelated to nested limiting and should be disregarded.

The answer by @spritsree would force the limiting to be performed in Python instead of at the Database level, where you want it to be done.

The details you are looking for are not implemented at the serializer level.

When you instantiate your serializer, you have to pass it the data that you wish to serialize. In your case, you should perform this reverse relationship limiting when gathering the data from the database.

I can only assume that you a 1-N relationship on Chat-Message. Therefore, you would **WISH** that you could do something like the following when writing your QuerySet:

```
QuerySet = Chat.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "messages", queryset=Message.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")[:50]
    )
)
```

However, [Django does not support slicing in prefetch related query sets](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26780). There is a work around described, but you need to perform an IN query, and this is the slowest way of solving this issue.

Instead, you should separate the message gathering into a separate query:

```
# assuming that you are only interested in a single chat
chat = Chat.objects.latest("created_at")
messages = Message.objects.filter(chat=chat).order_by("created_at")[:50]

# instantiate serializer
serializer = ChatSerializer(data={"chat": chat, "messages": messages, ...})
serializer.data
...
```

Comment: "The answer by @spritsree would force the limiting to be performed in Python instead of at the Database level, where you want it to be done."
I don't think your assessment is accurate here. Querysets are lazy, and slicing them will translate into a `LIMIT` SQL argument whenever the queryset is evaluated.

Comment: It depends on what `self.messages` was. If if was a QuerySet, then you are correct. However, most people would use `prefetch_related` here which would result in the slicing being performed in Python. This is what I was trying to avoid the OP from doing with that suggestion.